# what is the maximum number of faces with m edge and n vertex in planar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

what is the maximum number of faces with m edge and n vertex in planar graphs?

e=number of edges

v=number of vertices

f= number of faces

for example if  v=3 -> max(f)=2

v=4 -> max(f)=4 (a triangle with a point in inner face of it , connected to the three vertex)

v=6-> max(f)=8

Comment: what is meant by *face*?

Answer (score 2):

[Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) states

```
v − e + f = 2
```

Thus

```
f = 2 - v + e
```

So for given number of vertices and edges, the number of faces follows exactly.